# How to fix could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("", null) in the _CustomTabViewState

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a Flutter app. Here is my code.
`main.dart`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: const LoginPage(),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => _defaultHome,
        '/home': (context) => const BottomBar(),
        '/login': (context) => const LoginPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the home_screen:

```
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.logout,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          SharedService.logout(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ]),
```

Here is the share_service:

```
  static Future<void> logout(BuildContext context) async {
    await APICacheManager().deleteCache("login_details");
    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      '/login',
      (route) => false,
    );
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
E/flutter (22963): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/login", null) in the _CustomTabViewState.
E/flutter (22963): Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
E/flutter (22963):  1. For the "/" route, the "builder" property, if non-null, is used.
E/flutter (22963):  2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
E/flutter (22963):  3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "builder" and "routes".
E/flutter (22963):  4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
E/flutter (22963): Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
E/flutter (22963): #0      _CustomTabViewState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/models/tab_view.widget.dart:84:9)
E/flutter (22963): #1      _CustomTabViewState._onUnknownRoute (package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/models/tab_view.widget.dart:96:6)
E/flutter (22963): #2      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4092:37)
E/flutter (22963): #3      NavigatorState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4343:34)
E/flutter (22963): #4      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1941:34)
E/flutter (22963): #5      SharedService.logout (package:beast/services/shared_service.dart:44:15)
E/flutter (22963): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22963):
```

My question how can I fix this error because it is appearing on not only the logout button but any button I am clicking on except from the bottombar.

In the bottonbar I am using a `PersistentTabController` which when added all the other buttons were messed

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [`pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html), it states

> Push the route with the given name onto the navigator that most
> tightly encloses the given context, and then remove all the previous
> routes until the predicate returns true.

Since you predicate is `(route) => false` it never returns true for any route and continues to remove routes, which causes this error.

Therefore, you should update the predicate so that it returns true for some route. Or, if you want to remove all previous routes and push a new route, then use [`pushReplacementNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html) method instead.

> Replace the current route of the navigator that most tightly encloses
> the given context by pushing the route named routeName and then
> disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating
> in.

Comment: I changed it to true but it is still showing the same error